# MongoDB replica sets and data duplication

Tags: mongodb, replicaset

I am new to MongoDB and trying to understand replica sets. Specifically, I am trying to understand how MongoDB would handle the following situation:

1. A record is written to a table with a unique index on the primary Mongo member (Mongo 1).
2. Mongo #1 crashes before the new record is propagated to the secondary Mongo member (Mongo 2).
3. Mongo 2 and the arbiter elect Mongo 2 to be the primary.
4. The application attempts to create a duplicate record in the table. Because Mongo 2 is not aware of the record written to Mongo 1, the unique constraint is not enforced.
5. Mongo 1 becomes available again and replication resumes.

What happens next? Does Mongo 1 attempt to replicate the record to Mongo 2? Or Mongo 2 to Mongo 1? Or both simultaneously? How is the conflict resolved?

Comment: The question is "off-topic" as this is not a programming question and should be asked on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com). However it is basically asking someone to provide an answer for a question being asked in the [M202 MongoDB University course that is currently running](https://university.mongodb.com/courses/schedule). So you really need to try and work this out yourself, as this is the point.

Comment: Neil, point taken on the question being off-topic. I will consider reposting on dba.stackexchange.com. However, I don't understand your comment that working this out myself "is the point". Isn't this behavior documented somewhere? I assume it must be; I just can't find it after having spent a long time searching.

Comment: It is, and I will be glad to answer the question and point you to the docs when asked at the appropriate location. ;)

Comment: Thanks, Markus. I just re-posted on dba.stackexchange.com.